Adjusting white space of plot with respect to the plot box borders in Matplotlib
I want all of my plots' box size to be of uniform shape. I want to have same amount of white spaces around my plots with respect to the box borders (in all direction). I'm using bbox_inches='tight'. But as you can see, by default, matplotlib adjusts the white spaces with respect to the outer most element. In this case, the upper whitespace is adjusted with respect to the 0.0 tick in y-axis. That's why I'm not getting uniform spacing around the two plots.
I'm not using subplots. I have generated the 2 plots separately and adding them in Microsoft word, in table format. That's why I need same amount of white spaces with respect to the box borders. I just want, when I put the plot images in the table cells and make them of same size, all the plots' borders are of equal size.

Is there any way to fix it?

Just define the edge locations you want using fig.subplots_adjust instead of using tight_layout. Then you can define exactly the margins you want around your Axes, and guarantee they are the same for every plot you make that you want to match. For example: fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=0.9, left=0.1, right=0.9).

@tmdavison yeah, using subplots_adjust I can fix the white space. But I want my plot in square shape. So I'm using plt.gca().set_aspect() to make it square shaped. Therefore when I am saving the figure, it is saving it with all the extra white spaces that the show() window is showing. How can I fix this? How to ensure that the show window shows only the defined white spaces?

@tmdavison, I have figured it out. The problem is fixed now.
